# Why isn't a valid bit used for associative cache in processors

Tags: cpu-cache, cpu, caching

Direct map cache uses a valid bit to effectively know if any data is present to a specific cache-slot (aka line/index). If this is the only use of this bit, then I believe, once a line has v-bit set, it won't be unset until power off.

In addition, I wonder why similar optimization has not been done for associative (full or k-way) cache. Only reason I could imagine is that since for every read/write, a cache-slot will be filled, the cache will be filled pretty soon; and the probability of a slot being empty is zero in no time.

Any feedback will be much appreciated.

Comment: There *is* some form of validity bit for every line in every type of cache. Otherwise, at power-up, tags will be random and there is the risk of a false hit.

Comment: @ Alan Merigot - I thought CPU caches are volatile! If so, why would tags be random at power-up

Comment: They are volatile. Their content is lost at power down. At power up, the content of a flip-flop/memory cell is undetermined for electronic reasons. So, it is  part of the boot process to invalidate all cache blocks.